# How to test Stripe's invoice_pdf property when it keeps changing?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stripe-payments

In my Rails 6 app I have a very simple controller that displays download links to a user's Stripe invoice PDFs:

```
class ReceiptsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user

  def index
    receipts = current_account.receipts
  end

  def show
    receipt = current_account.receipts.find(params[:id])
    stripe_invoice = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve(receipt.stripe_invoice_id)
    redirect_to stripe_invoice.invoice_pdf
  end

end
```

Since Stripe doesn't provide *permanent* invoice URLs (please correct me if I am wrong), I am storing each invoice's Stripe ID in the database and then use that ID to lookup the current URL to the invoice PDF from the Stripe API.

The problem is that this works *most of the time* but not all the time. The spec that I created for the controller `show` action fails in about 20 % of cases because the two URLs do not match:

```
describe ReceiptsController, :type => :controller do

  before :each do
    @account = FactoryBot.create(:activated_account)
    @user = @account.users.create(FactoryBot.attributes_for(:user))
    sign_in(@user)
  end

  describe 'GET #show' do

    # The implementation details of this block don't really matter
    before :each do
      Customers::FindOrCreate.call(@account)
      stripe_subscription = Subscriptions::CreateRemote.call(@account,:payment_behavior => "default_incomplete")
      @stripe_invoice = stripe_subscription.latest_invoice
      @receipt = Receipts::Create.call(@stripe_invoice)
    end

    # This test fails in about 20 % of cases because the redirect does not go to @stripe_invoice.invoice_pdf but a slightly different URL
    it "redirects to Stripe invoice PDF" do
      get :show, :params => {:id => @receipt}
      expect(response).to redirect_to @stripe_invoice.invoice_pdf
    end

  end

end
```

How can this be? Does the `invoice_pdf` property of a Stripe invoice change every few seconds? I've been trying to work this out for days now but can't get my head around it.

---

**Addition:**

This is a typical test failure that I get quite often:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_105jfm2HzYSlmhv7/test_YWNjdF8xMDJqc20yS3pZUmxzaHc0LF9NMGZONnFzNUpPTjlObVprd0hvdGpIdWFUamJHTTVxLDQ3Njc3MDY30200oOxX3A1/pdf?s=ap> but was a redirect to <https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_105jfm2HzYSlmhv7/test_YWNjdF8xMDJqc20yS3pZUmxzaHc0LF9NMGZONnFzNUpPTjlObVprd0hvdGpIdWFUamJHTTVxLDQ3Njc3MDY402001iYCSUbn/pdf?s=ap>.
       Expected "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_105jfm2HzYSlmhv7/test_YWNjdF8xMDJqc20yS3pZUmxzaHc0LF9NMGZONnFzNUpPTjlObVprd0hvdGpIdWFUamJHTTVxLDQ3Njc3MDY30200oOxX3A1F/pdf?s=ap" to be === "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_105jfm2HzYSlmhv7/test_YWNjdF8xMDJqc20yS3pZUmxzaHc0LF9NMGZONnFzNUpPTjlObVprd0hvdGpIdWFUamJHTTVxLDQ3Njc3MDY402001iYCSUbn/pdf?s=ap".
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, invoice_pdf [1] URLs are not static and therefore retrieving the invoice object [2] to obtain the invoice_pdf is best practice. If the invoice has not been finalized, the invoice_pdf value will be null and a redirect will fail. Is it possible that your test doesn’t account for this and causing the test failures? What purpose is the redirection test serving? Wouldn’t an invoice_pdf value be sufficient for a successful test?

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object?lang=ruby#invoice_object-invoice_pdf
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve

Comment: @JohnnyJavascript, thanks for your help. No, all the invoices that are being tested have been finalized. There are no null values here. I just added the error message of a typical test failure in my original post above. As you can see, there are always URLs present but sometimes they slightly differ at the end which is why some of the tests fail (regularly!).